# Keeping track of background processes?

Tags: multithreading, perl

I want to run a bunch of processes called by Perl, but only want to run 8 at a time (the number of cores on my machine).  For example:

```
for ( my $i = 1; $i <= 20; $i++) {
        my $command = `some_process $i &`;
}
```

That would run 20 threads of the process, but I would run out of CPU and/or memory.  I want to run 8 to start with, and then when a process finishes, launch another one until 20 are completed.

What is an easy way to do this?

Comment: Parallel::ForkManager

Comment: Your queston is confusing two concepts. Processes VS threads.

Comment: And tasks. Do they need to be executed as different processes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using `wait` bultin (see perlfunc(1) manpage):

```
for ( my $i = 1; $i <= 20; $i++) {
  wait if $i > 8;
  my $command = `some_process $i &`;
}
```

But there is no guarantee the processes will be distributed evenly among the processors.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking at the threads perldoc
http://perldoc.perl.org/threads.html

Count your threads. When one finishes, then make a new thread
and just keep the # of threads <= 8.

This may not equally distribute the load, but it will let you run
several concurrent tasks, and you can limit how many you want to run.